# Desktop icons gone in 22.04

Tags: 22.04, desktop-icons

I upgraded from 21.10 to 22.04. Everything was fine. But when I changed the wallpaper, all my desktop icons are gone now. I see a plain desktop with wallpaper and icons dock.

How can I bring back the desktop icons? Thanks.

Edit 1: Checked " Extensions", no Desktop NG extension available.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Apparently, there was an issue during your upgrade where the gnome shell extension that provides the desktop icons was not properly upgraded.

Install the extension:

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng
```

Logging out then back in should enable the extension, and thus give you the desktop icons back.

In case you do not see the icons, check whether the extension is correctly installed and active using the Extensions tool. If needed, install the Extensions tool:

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-prefs
```

Comment: The first command works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The new Ubuntu 22.04.1 does not support the `Type=Link` in desktop icons. So make it an Application like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Exec=firefox https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
Icon=/home/chiel/Pictures/Icons/Wikipediaglobe.png
Name[en_US]=Wiki_en
```

Make sure the extension is `.desktop`.

Comment: Thanks for correcting the lay out of my entry.

Answer (score 1):

In my case reinstalling Gnome Control Center solved the problem.

```
sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-control-center
```