# No Application Icons in Dock after Upgrading to 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: 22.04, dock

After I upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04.1 I don't see any icons in Ubuntu's dock. There is only the 9-dot-icon, which opens the applications overview. Even if I try to add an application manually ("add to favourites") the dock stays empty.

What could be the reason? And how can I fix it?

This is how the dock appears at the moment:

[image: Current state of the dock after upgrading]

edit: I noticed, that the dock icons are present, when I log in with "Gnome" or "Gnome with Xorg", but not with one of the "Ubuntu" options.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Desktop icons gone in 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406236/desktop-icons-gone-in-22-04)

Comment: Unfortunately not. I can enable and disable desktop icons, but the dock stays empty.

Comment: I had the same issue after accidentally installing xfce, what I did was `sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop --reinstall` and then use gnome tweak tool to enable dash to dock, worth a try

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disabling the "Ubuntu Dock" and "Ubuntu AppIndicators" built-in extensions should fix this.

Simply open your applications overview (or "Windows" key) and type "Extensions". Then at the bottom of the window, just disable the Ubuntu Dock and Ubuntu AppIndicators.

A short term solution on a per-occurrence basis is running a command to reload the dock. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then type `r` then press <kbd>Return</kbd>. This will reload and bring the icons back.

- Credits: Axel29, frisodubach, votdev on the report of this issue on the github for the dash-to-dock project, link here: https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock/issues/1522

Answer (score 2):

Try this command:

```
dconf reset -f "/org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/"
```

Comment: I tried out @gianthair's solution first and then this one. But seems to me, your answers works, too. Thx alot. Seems like I have not enough reputation to upvote or select your answer as the correct one after choosing the first, sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

Do `sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop --reinstall` as suggested by @Cagri.
It worked for me, this happened because I had tried to delete all python packages.

Comment: This helped for me as well, after upgrading to 23.04.