# Red icons in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: display, icons, 22.04

Since I installed Ubuntu 22.04, I have had issues rendering some icons.

Most are on the top bar, as the picture below shows, however, there are some apps that do not render as well. The screenshot app is an example.

Any idea how to solve this?

I've updated DING and used the extension manager and everything seems okay.

Thanks for any help.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjrzi.png)

Comment: Same problem here =/ 
Did you find out any solution ?

Comment: Yeah, not sure why but I got it to work. Check my answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Desktop icons gone in 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406236/desktop-icons-gone-in-22-04)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually got it to work using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406236/desktop-icons-gone-in-22-04).

I had already done this and I checked and the extension was enabled. I decided to try again and after rebooting the icons showed up.

Not sure what happened but it worked for me.