# Ubuntu 22.04 icons error

Tags: icons

I install Ubuntu 22.04 and after a few stars a lot of icons went red, like in [this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMJAp.png).

I tried to use this answer [Desktop icons gone in 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406236/desktop-icons-gone-in-22-04), but it done nothing.

```
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng is already the newest version (43-2ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 108 not upgraded.
```

Can anybody help me pls? :)

Comment: Try rerunning those commands in your link with `--reinstall` switch right after `sudo apt install` before the package name.

Comment: Didn't work :(.

Comment: I wonder if you are missing the applications that the icons point to?  Maybe the icons that were being supplied moved?  You can check by finding the `.desktop` file of it and see what icon file it is trying to load and then see if that icon exists on the system